# Can't find Google Now in CyanogenMod 10.0 for Galaxy S2

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.1-jelly-bean, google-now

I flashed CM 10.0 (Android 4.1.2) to my Galaxy S2 (i777), and it doesn't seem like Google Now is installed. It doesn't show in the list when I go to Google Play, but I do have Google Search v1.4.1.299849 installed.

Any idea how I can install Google Now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a version of Google Search that doesn't include Google Now. The easiest way to fix this would be to install a new version of the Google Search app. I have linked to the googlenow apk below so that you can install the version I had on my device.

This should then allow you to access Google Now by pressing the Google Search option in the app drawer, or using the quick search bar on the default launcher.

[GoogleNow.apk](http://liamwli.co.uk/GoogleNow.apk)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open Google Now you have to press the Home button for a couple of seconds. In my case Google Now opens after one second or so. But it could be that, if you haven't opened Google Now before, it can take some more time.

Another possibility is that your Google Search version is not the latest available version. At this moment I have version 2.2.10.546669 on my phone, which supports Google Now (January 7th, 2013).

Comment: When I press and hold Home button, I get list of running apps

Comment: @ndsmyter This is untrue. The long press home button is for the recent apps list on *all* Android devices, unless your device maker has changed this in their own ROM.

Comment: @LiamW I removed my comment, you're right

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled Google Search updates then updated again.  It works fine now.